# SQL get date when specific fields or columns are changed

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I would like to create a column that would store a date only when specific fields/columns are filled with data or have their data changed.

Lets say I have a table named contracts, which has sales person, product sold, date which it was sold etc... Then should someone change the sales person only... Then the date which the sales person was changed should be updated in a specific column. This column should not capture the date when any column is changed, no, just sales person. Been trying to think of the logic to do that but do not know where to start...

Even if I need to use some php its ok please assist... or hints, ideas, suggestion to guide me would be highly appreciated

Comment: Triggers are perfect for this!

Comment: Indeed do this via the db itself.

Comment: You can use After trigger for this purpose which will set to execute after every Update statement executed on your table and in this trigger you can check if specific column has been modified and accordingly update your Date column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use `AFTER TRIGGER` on your table. Create column in your table for example `DateUpdated` with `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT GETDATE()`

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts
(  
   ........................,
   SalesPerson NVARCHAR(60), 
   ProductSold NVARCHAR(60), 
   Date DATE,
   DateUpdated DATETIME
      CONSTRAINT DF_Contracts_DateUpdated DEFAULT (GETDATE())
)
```

Create trigger on your table which will update `DateUpdated` field everytime when any data will be modified.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
   ON Contracts
   FOR UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON
      UPDATE Contracts AS C
      SET DateUpdated = GETDATE()
      FROM INSERTED AS I
      WHERE I.Table1ID = C.Table1ID
    END
```